# Herkunft „Erst [Deutschland], dann [die ganze Welt!]“?

Tags: phrase, political-correctness

Ein relativ häufig auftretendes Muster, bspw. in Zeitungsüberschriften, ist *erst …, dann …* In der Phrase steht selten ein Verb, höchstens das explizite *erobern (wollen/werden/haben)*, das sonst nur (oft im übertragenen Sinne) impliziert ist. Gefühlt besonders häufig tritt als zweiter Teil *dann die ganze Welt* auf. Statt *erst* kann auch *zuerst* verwendet werden, welches auch nachgestellt sein kann: *… zuerst, dann …* Intuitiv übersetze und ergänze ich Trumps “America First!” so, obowohl ich weiß, dass *first* hier nicht als **zeitliche** Priorität gemeint ist.

Mir ist, als sei „Erst [Deutschland], dann die ganze Welt!“ im 19./20. Jahrhundert ein Schlachtruf verschiedener politischer Ideologien gewesen, konnte das aber noch nicht hinreichend bestätigen. Ist das tatsächlich der Ursprung dieser Floskel? Wird sie ggf. daher als problematisch angesehen (und journalistisch trotzdem regelmäßig verwendet)?

Comment: Den Teil und das Ganze zu erwähnen, ist eine typische Rethorik-Figur. *Urbi et Orbi*, das der Papst verkündet, heisst ja im Prinzip dasselbe, und Ovid schrieb *Romanae spatium est urbis et orbis idem.*

Comment: Hmm, _urbi et orbi_ ist laut dt. Wikipedia Paronomasie und Homöoteleuton, aber beides bezieht sich nur auf den Klang. Eine Klimax ist normalerweise dreiteilig und ein Bathos normalerweise extremer zugespitzt. Aber ja, eine rhetorische Figur ist es bestimmt, nur finde ich ihren exakten Namen nicht.

Comment: man *könnte* sagen, es wäre *pars cum toto*. Aber das müsste man natürlich erst erfinden.

Comment: Aber ich glaube, der richtige Begriff ist (vielleicht) *Synekdoche*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Das klingt nach einer Anspielung auf die Zeile

> Heute da hört uns Deutschland, und morgen die ganze Welt

aus dem NS-Lied
["Es zittern die morschen Knochen"](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hans_Baumann)
(wobei umstritten ist, ob es im Originaltext
"da hört" oder "gehört" heißt – beide Versionen wurden gesungen).

Comment: siehe auch "New York (...) if we can make it there, we make it everywhere" oder "first we take Manhatten, then we take Berlin", beides freilich deutlich jünger. Oder auch "Urbi et Orbi" - (In Rom und außerhalb).

Comment: @userunknown Es geht speziell um die Formulierung "... die ganze Welt".

Comment: @Uwe *orbi* **ist** diese Formulierung.

Comment: Ahja, ich kann _heute …, morgen …_ mit _erst …, dann …_ durcheinandergebracht haben. Kein Wunder, dass ich es so nicht gefunden habe.

Comment: @tofro Bei "urbi et orbi" fehlt aber sowohl das implizierte Erobern als auch die zeitliche Abfolge,

Comment: Ich sehe möglicherweise nicht gut, aber in "...die ganze Welt" kann ich kein implizites Erobern finden. Auch im Lied nicht, zumindestens nicht, solange man es mit "...hört uns Deutschland..." zitiert.

Comment: @tofro Es steht aber in der Frage. Bei "first we take Manhatten, then we take Berlin" steckt die Idee auch drin, vielleicht auch noch bei "if we can make it there, we make it everywhere", aber bei "urbi et orbi" gerade eben nicht.

Comment: @Uwe: Das waren auch nur lose Assoziationen. Wer da was kannte und ob eines ein Einfluss für ein anderes war ist mir vollkommen unbekannt. Eine aggressivere Note kann aber auch im Laufe der Zeit dazukommen. An dieses Lied musste ich aber auch sofort bei der Frage denken.